# using session variables while deploying stored procedures-snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a situation where I am pushing my stored procedure DDL into git repository. These codes have some environment specific codes, like I have dev,qa and prd, while I need to replace every time while deploying.

What I am looking for is to be able to use variables, that could be replaced while deploying. Something like this

```
var env= 'dev';

create or replace procedure test
returns varchar
language javascript
as
$$
insert into raw_$env.employee values(1);
$$;
```

When I run this code I want to have the code deployed like this.

```
create or replace procedure test
returns varchar
language javascript
as
$$
insert into raw_raw.employee values(1);
$$;
```

Answer (score 1):

To specify the dynamic schema name, you can use IDENTIFIER().  Then use the javascript stored procedure API to execute.

```
create or replace procedure test()
returns text
language javascript
execute as caller
as
$$
  snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: `set t = 'raw_' || $env || '.employee'` }).execute()
  snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: `insert into identifier($t) values(1)` }).execute()
  return 'SUCCESS'
$$;

set env= 'dev';

call test();
```

You may want to specify the database as well.

---

UPDATE -- Static solution, hard coding the 'env' parameter

RUN IN SNOWSQL

```
!define env=dev;

create or replace procedure test()
returns text
language javascript
execute as caller
as
$$
  snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: `insert into raw_&env.employee values(1)` }).execute()  return 'SUCCESS'
$$;
```

To verify that the substition is static:

```
select get_ddl('procedure','test()')
```

The env parameter can also be defined in a config file or on the [SNOWSQL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql-use.html#using-variables) command line.

Comment: I don't want to use the variable within the stored procedure, I want to deploy the code using the variable. Like while running the DDL, it should replace the variable into the actual value and deploy

Comment: The SNOWSQL CLI can do that for you.  I added an example.  You could also use Python or another language with a Snowflake API.

Comment: I think this is the closest we can get

Comment: If you want a pure Snowflake SQL solution, you can have a Snowflake procedure TEST_CREATE() that creates the that creates the TEST() procedure.  TEST_CREATE would store a template of TEST() in a javascript string, read the contents of $env into a javascript variable, do a string substitution, and then execute the template.

Comment: the variable didn't get replaced in the procedure when using the snowsql method